How do I pick the minimum number of unique items in a 2D array, such that these picked items appear on every row?
For example,
I have a 2D array of:
{ [1,2,3,4],
  [2,4,6,8],
  [8,7,1,5],
  [0,9,3,10] }

It consists of the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.
In this example, you can see that no one of the elements exist on all rows. Thus, I have to pick [3,8] because these elements cover all 4 rows. Picking [1,2,3] can also cover all rows, but the minimum solution is 2 elements, which is [3,8].
Pre-condition: No duplicate items can exist on the same row. E.g.
{ [1,2,2,4],
  [2,4,4,8],
  [8,7,7,5],
  [0,9,7,10] }

Is invalid because some elements appear more than once in a row.
I would like to do this using programmatically, using any language, preferred C++ or Java. My actual dataset is 96 unique items, on about 80 rows.
